# CSS: Text inputs and select box vertical alignment

Tags: html, css

I am having a tough time trying to get the text to align vertically in the middle of my select boxes. I think I have everything as simplified as I can get it while keeping the functionality and customization that I want, but you can see in the example that while I can get the text input and the select fields to be the same height, the text in the select fields does not vertically align in the center.

What am I missing?

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.col-6 {
 flex: 1;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
 flex-basis: 50%;
 max-width: 50%;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
hr {
 display: block;
 border: none;
 margin: 2em 0;
 clear: both;
}

/* **** Start Form Elements **** */

.field-icon-append {
 position: relative;
}
.field-icon-append span {
 position: absolute;
 line-height: 1;
 top: 25%;
 right: 10px; 
 pointer-events: none;
}
.field-icon-append input, .field-icon-append select {
 padding-right: 30px;
}
input, select {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #acacac;
 min-height: 40px;
 color: inherit;
    padding: 0.4em;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: auto;
}
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
input.narrow, select.narrow {
 min-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='all' />

<div class="row">

 <div class="col-6">
  
  <div class="field-icon-append">
  
   <span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
   
   <input type="text" name="EmailAddress" />

  </div>
 
 </div> <!-- /.col-6 -->
 
 <div class="col-6">
  
  <div class="field-icon-append">
   
   <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></span>
  
   <select>
             <option value="1">First</option>
             <option value="2">Second</option>
             <option value="3">Third</option>
             <option value="4">Fourth</option>
         </select>

  </div>
 
 </div> <!-- /.col-6 -->

</div> <!-- /.row -->

<hr />

<div class="row">

 <div class="col-6">
  
  <div class="field-icon-append">
  
   <span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
   
   <input type="text" name="Search" class="narrow" />

  </div>
 
 </div> <!-- /.col-6 -->
 
 <div class="col-6">
  
  <div class="field-icon-append">
   
   <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></span>
  
   <select class="narrow">
             <option value="1">First</option>
             <option value="2">Second</option>
             <option value="3">Third</option>
             <option value="4">Fourth</option>
         </select>

  </div>
 
 </div> <!-- /.col-6 -->

</div> <!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: if the font-size is 11px, you could try line-height:11px as well.

Comment: yeah just start setting line-height to the same value as the select height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've simly added `class="mid"` to `<select />` and the css

```
.mid {
  text-indent: 50%;
}
```

This is how it looks till the end:

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.col-6 {
 flex: 1;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
 flex-basis: 50%;
 max-width: 50%;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
hr {
 display: block;
 border: none;
 margin: 2em 0;
 clear: both;
}

/* **** Start Form Elements **** */

.field-icon-append {
 position: relative;
}
.field-icon-append span {
 position: absolute;
 line-height: 1;
 top: 25%;
 right: 10px; 
 pointer-events: none;
}
.field-icon-append input, .field-icon-append select {
 padding-right: 30px;
}
input, select {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #acacac;
 min-height: 40px;
 color: inherit;
    padding: 0.4em;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: auto;
}
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
input.narrow, select.narrow {
 min-height: 30px;
}

.mid {
  text-indent: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='all' />

<div class="row">

 <div class="col-6">
  
  <div class="field-icon-append">
  
   <span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
   
   <input type="text" name="EmailAddress" />

  </div>
 
 </div> <!-- /.col-6 -->
 
 <div class="col-6">
  
  <div class="field-icon-append">
   
   <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></span>
  
   <select class="mid">
             <option value="1">First</option>
             <option value="2">Second</option>
             <option value="3">Third</option>
             <option value="4">Fourth</option>
         </select>

  </div>
 
 </div> <!-- /.col-6 -->

</div> <!-- /.row -->

<hr />

<div class="row">

 <div class="col-6">
  
  <div class="field-icon-append">
  
   <span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
   
   <input type="text" name="Search" class="narrow" />

  </div>
 
 </div> <!-- /.col-6 -->
 
 <div class="col-6">
  
  <div class="field-icon-append">
   
   <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></span>
  
   <select class="narrow mid">
             <option value="1">First</option>
             <option value="2">Second</option>
             <option value="3">Third</option>
             <option value="4">Fourth</option>
         </select>

  </div>
 
 </div> <!-- /.col-6 -->

</div> <!-- /.row -->
```

That's the maximum you can do, `<option />` tag cannot be aligned to the middle..

Comment: "vertically" is mentioned twice in op's post

Comment: I see that the text is already aligned vertically in the select tag oO